# How can I match all characters up to the second to last white space character in a string?

Tags: regular-expression, vim

I'm trying to replace the substring "Abbey Street E.2 " in the string "Abbey Street E.2 Buckfast Street" to get the result "Buckfast Street".

I tried `:s/[^ ]* [^ ]* //`but I'm getting "Street".

Basically I'm trying to delete everything upto the second to last white space character, using the substitute command.

My operating system is MacOs and I am using vim.

Also, my understanding of the above substitute command is match any non white space character up to a white space character, then match any non white space character up to a white space character. Is this correct?

Comment: Is the target string always at the end of the line? Is the target string always "Buckfast Street"? If the removal string always "Abbey Street E.2 "? Is the removal string always at the beginning of the line? There are many things that can help make the solution easier to write if you can remove some possible conditions

Comment: @user1794469 this is one of several thousand lines in a file that I need to run the substitute command on, so the target string (i.e. pattern) is not static.

Answer (score 2):

In sed (easier for me to test in it), we can build the regex needed.
A `[^ ]*` should match any word (if there are no punctuation characters). So:

```
$ a="Abbey Street E.2 Buckfast Street"
$ echo "$a" | sed 's/[^ ]*//'
 Street E.2 Buckfast Street
```

will remove the first word. Note that the space has been left in the output. We need then to remove the space as well. And repeat the same three times to remove the 3 leading words (and leave the last two):

```
$ echo "$a" | sed 's/\([^ ]* \)\{3\}//'
Buckfast Street
```

But in your description you stated: *upto the second to last white space character*, that's diferent. Removing three words from a 6 word sentence will leave 3 words, not the **last two**.

So, we need to work backwards, and, to see the effects of the regex, I'll capture each section and print it separated with `|==|`.

Your basic idea to capture a word was to use `[^ ]*`, and yes, it could work (sometimes). Using -E to avoid the `\`'s:

```
$ echo "$a" | sed -E 's/([^ ]*)(.*)/\1|==|\2/'
Abbey|==| Street E.2 Buckfast Street
```

It captures the first word in the first parentheses and "all the rest" (`.*`) in the second parentheses. But, if we want to reverse the regex:

```
$ echo "$a" | sed -E 's/(.*)([^ ]*)/\1|==|\2/'
Abbey Street E.2 Buckfast Street|==|
```

What happens here is that the `.*` captures everything and the next part captures **zero** characters (which is a valid result for an `*`). We need some **anchor or delimiter**, some character or point that forces the regex to match an specific point. We can use the space as the delimiter, and the $ as the anchor to ensure the word selected is actually the **last** of the string:

```
$ echo "$a" | sed -E 's/(.* )([^ ]*)$/\1|==|\2/'
Abbey Street E.2 Buckfast |==|Street
```

Repeating the spaces we match the **last two words**:

```
$ echo "$a" | sed -E 's/(.* )([^ ]* [^ ]*)$/\1|==|\2/'
Abbey Street E.2 |==|Buckfast Street
```

Now, select the part that you want to keep and/or erase:

```
$ echo "$a" | sed -E 's/(.* )([^ ]* [^ ]*)$/\2/'
Buckfast Street
```

Of course, at this point there is no need to capture the first part:

```
$ echo "$a" | sed -E 's/.* ([^ ]* [^ ]*)$/\1/'
Buckfast Street
```

The BRE equivalent of this ERE works in vim:

```
:s/.* \([^ ]* [^ ]*\)$/\1/
```

Comment: Nice, +1. Why are you using two capture groups in solution 3? The first one isn't actually used as far as I can tell. Any reason not to just do `sed 's/.* ([^ ]* [^ ]*)$/\1/'`?

Comment: I think I understand this part `sed 's/ [^ ]* [^ ]*$/zzz/` to mean from a white space characer match every non white space character up to a white space characteter then match every non white space character to the end of the line, but isn't the first white space character after "Abbey" so why is your `sed`command matching the last two words "BuckFast Street"?

Comment: I guess this `sed -e 's/^(\S*\s){3}//'` might also do the trick.

Comment: @terdon The capture groups were meant to explain what is in the answer now. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia Because the only way to comply with the whole regex, basically: from an space to the end of the string, is to actually match at the end of the string (where the $ is).

Comment: @bey0nd Well, if you mean to write `sed -E 's/^(\S*\s){3}//'` (-e has a completely different meaning) and your sed understand `\S` and `\s`, then yes, that works the same way for the specific example of "Abbey Street E.2 Buckfast Street". But for a sentence with 8 or 10 words, the result will not be: "the last two words". It will remove the *3 leading words* not keep the *2 trailing words* as the OP said.

Comment: No I meant to write -e, as it works like this on my system. Furthermore the OP clearly states _Basically I'm trying to delete everything upto the second to last white space character_ which, in his example, means deleting the leading three words and not keeping the last two (even so in the example the result is the same). If out of a sentence with 8 to 10 words he wants to keep the last 4, 3 or 2 words is pure speculation.

Comment: @bey0nd What does `-e` mean in your system?. Is there an equivalent option that works on all systems?

Comment: @ Isaac  according to `man sed` it stands for _-e script, --expression=script "add the script to the commands to be executed"_

Comment: @ bey0nd If you are using GNU sed, then you have to either scape the `(` and `) ` or use the `-E` option.

Answer (score 0):

In vim you will probably need to escape the `()`. I have something like this:

```
:s/.* \(.\+ .\+$\)/\1/
```

It will break on lines that don't have at least 2 spaces.

Comment: The `.` also matches the spaces. Did you try it?

Comment: I did, did you?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is:
`:s/^\S*\s\S*\s\S*\s//`
where ^ stands for the beginning of the line,
\s stands for 'white-space' (space or tab)
and \S stands for 'none-white-space'

This could be 'shortened' to:
`:s/^\(\S*\s\)\{3\}//`
which stands for three occurrences of 'any amount of none-white-spaces' followed by one whitespace

This should match and delete "Abbey Street E.2 " and leave "Buckfast Street".

Comment: If what is meant is: *Remove the 3 leading words*, then yes this works. But what was written was: *retain the **last two** words* .

Comment: First statement of the OP: _I'm trying to replace the substring "Abbey Street E.2 " in the string "Abbey Street E.2 Buckfast Street" to get the result "Buckfast Street"._ Then she/he goes on explaining the attempt to archive this and asks if her/his understanding of this attempt is correct.  I can't find any _'retain the last to words' in her/his post. I think that is your interpretation of the post whereby I was helping her/him with the understanding of space and white space in her/his approach.

Answer (score 0):

**We also can use awk to print last two words of a string:**

```
awk '{printf(NF>1)?$(NF-1)" "$NF"\n":(NF>0)?$NF"\n":""}'
```

**Examples:**

```
$ echo ""|awk '{printf(NF>1)?$(NF-1)" "$NF"\n":(NF>0)?$NF"\n":""}'
$ echo "1"|awk '{printf(NF>1)?$(NF-1)" "$NF"\n":(NF>0)?$NF"\n":""}'
1
$ echo "1 22"|awk '{printf(NF>1)?$(NF-1)" "$NF"\n":(NF>0)?$NF"\n":""}'
1 22
$ echo "1 22 333"|awk '{printf(NF>1)?$(NF-1)" "$NF"\n":(NF>0)?$NF"\n":""}'
22 333
$ echo "1 22 333 4444"|awk '{printf(NF>1)?$(NF-1)" "$NF"\n":(NF>0)?$NF"\n":""}'
333 4444
```

---

**In case of sed, I would use:**

```
sed 's/^.*\s\([^ \t]\+\)\s\+\([^ \t]\+\)\s*$/\1 \2/g'
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo " 1  22   3333  4444   "|sed 's/^.*\s\([^ \t]\+\)\s\+\([^ \t]\+\)\s*$/\1 \2/g'
3333 4444
```

The complexity is increased by the need to properly work with lines containing few in a row spaces (or tab symbols), also possible extra space(s) at the end of the line, the output in this case: two separated by one space words.
However, this case doesn't cover lines with only one word or lines with only spaces, it will print them unchanged. We can take care about it, but it will make the sed command even more complex, so I skip it here.

---

**Updated.**

**In case of MacOS sed**, it looks like this (I excluded tab symbols to make it easier):

```
sed 's/^.* \([^ ][^ ]*\)  *\([^ ][^ ]*\) *$/\1 \2/g'
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo " 1  22   3333  4444   "|sed 's/^.* \([^ ][^ ]*\)  *\([^ ][^ ]*\) *$/\1 \2/g'
3333 4444
```

Comment: Maybe `awk '{print $(NF-1),$NF}'` could work.

Comment: It depends on input. In case of string containing two words or more, it works. But in case of string from one word - it prints it twice. And in case of empty string (or consisting of spaces), it returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

Need to anchor. As you want the last two words, work from the end: `$` matches end of line, then non-white (one or more), i.e. `[^ ][^ ]*`, then one space, and so on. Group the interesting part (force it's start after a space), replace the full line by the bracketed part. Dunno offhand if `sed(1)` uses extended regexes everywhere, I'm using that here:

```
sed -ne 's/^.* ([^ ][^ ]* [^ ][^ ]*)/\1/p'
```

Completely untested, use at your own risk.

Comment: Why did you put two times `[^ ]` one after another? I think you wanted to ensure that there is at least one non space character. I'd suggest to use the `+` operator (one on more times) instead of the `*` operator (zero or more times). That results in `sed -ne 's/^.* ([^ ]\+ [^ ]\+)/\1/p'
`